# How to make Trackpad scroll only in one direction?

Tags: macos, trackpad, settings, accessibility

When I try to scroll a text view using the Trackpad moving my two finders in the the vertical direction, it also moves slightly in the horizontal direction, which makes the movement to appear jerky. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Like for instance some kind of threshold to stop the horizontal scroll if the movement is more prominent in the vertical direction?

I tried searching for something like that in the system settings, but there is no such thing.